# Recursion vs No Recursion in JS Binary Search on Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, binary-search

I've written out a recursive method for finding a *single item in an array which is not repeated (whereas all other items are in pairs and next to one another)*. My question is, can this be done without recursion (perhaps with a while loop) and is using a loop within the function more effective (in terms of memory) than just using recursion?

Current solution:

```
function findSingularElement(arr, low, high) {
  // base cases
  if (arr.length < 3) return console.log('Invalid length of array.');
  if (low > high) return;
  if (low == high) return console.log(arr[low]);

  var mid = low + (high - low) / 2;

  if (mid % 2 === 0) {
    if (arr[mid] == arr[mid + 1]) {
      return findSingularElement(arr, mid + 2, high);
    } else {
      return findSingularElement(arr, low, mid);
    }
  } else {
    if (arr[mid] == arr[mid - 1]) {
      return findSingularElement(arr, mid + 1, high);
    } else {
      return findSingularElement(arr, low, mid - 1);
    }
  }
}

var array = [1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7, 8, 8];
```

Thank you.

Comment: "yes" to both questions... )) Instead of rec calls, just update `low` and `high` and loop while `low <= high`.

Comment: Is expected result `4`?

Comment: @guest271314 yes, the expected in this case is `4`.

Comment: If you think about how recursion actually works, with pushing stuff onto the stack and whatnot, any recursive algorithm can be rewritten using loops.

Comment: @georg I'm going in circles here (no pun intended). Would you mind responding with an example? I'm beginning to go cross-eyed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove recursion from your function, just replace recursive calls with appropriate variable assignments:

```
function findSingularElement1(arr) {
    if (arr.length < 3)
        throw('Invalid length of array.');

    var low = 0, high = arr.length - 1;

    while (low < high) {

        var mid = low + (high - low) / 2;

        if (mid % 2 === 0) {
            if (arr[mid] == arr[mid + 1]) {
                low = mid + 2;
            } else {
                high = mid;
            }
        } else {
            if (arr[mid] == arr[mid - 1]) {
                low = mid + 1;
            } else {
                high = mid - 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return low == high ? arr[low] : null;
}
```

That said, your whole approach seems overcomplicated, you can easily find an unpaired item with a simple loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 2)
    if (array[i] != array[i + 1])
        return array[i];
```

(Assuming the array is sorted, and each item occurs exactly once or twice).

Comment: Thank you. You're correct that binary search seems like overkill for this. I think the intention behind this was to just practice more binary search, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

My answer, just having fun!

```
var numberArray = [1, 3, 6, 8, 9, 11, 16, 27, 33, 37, 56, 78];

function recursiveBinary(sortedArray, target, start, end) {
    var start = start || 0;
  var end = end || sortedArray.length;
    var middle = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);

    if (start > end) {
    return -1;
  }

  if (target === sortedArray[middle]) {
    return sortedArray[middle];
  } else if (target < sortedArray[middle]) {
    return recursiveBinary(sortedArray, target, start, middle - 1);
  } else if (target > sortedArray[middle]) {
    return recursiveBinary(sortedArray, target, middle + 1, end);
  }

}

var sum = recursiveBinary(numberArray, 9);
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything that is done with recursion, can be replaced by loops. The only thing that recursion can do and loops can't is making the code easy and clean.
Recursion can be removed in a binary search by replacing the base condition with a loop.

```
 function binarySearch(arr,ele){
  let low = 0;
  let high = arr.length-1;
  while(low<=high){
   let mid = Math.floor((low+high)/2) 
   if(arr[mid]==ele) 
     return true;
   else if(arr[mid]>ele)
     high = mid-1;
   else
     low = mid+1;
    }
  return false;
 }
```